# Combine two tables, exclude same records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
T1 
A  
B  
C  
D

T2  
A  
B  
E  
F  
G
```

Now I want to have query that will combine those two tables but exclude 
same records. The output table should be like:

```
T1T2 
C  
D  
E  
F  
G
```

How to do that?

Comment: get both table in an array and merge them and then use array_unique and insert into the 3 table

Comment: Use a full outer join and select only non-maching (null) records, details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` and exclude common part. You can simulate it with:

```
SELECT T1.col_name
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2
  ON T1.col_name = T2.col_name
WHERE T2.col_name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT T2.col_name
FROM T2 
LEFT JOIN T1
  ON T1.col_name = T2.col_name
WHERE T1.col_name IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b178/1/0)**</kbd>

```
╔══════════╗
║ col_name ║
╠══════════╣
║ C        ║
║ D        ║
║ E        ║
║ F        ║
║ G        ║
╚══════════╝
```

---

More info: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

[image]

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE A.Key IS NULL OR B.Key IS NULL
```

Unfortunately `MySQL` does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN` so I used union of 2 `LEFT JOIN`.

[image]

[image]

<sup>All images from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins</sup>

## Addendum

> But what if I have two different tables with different columns, but both of them have one same column? The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

You could easily expand it with additional columns.

```
SELECT 'T1' AS tab_name, T1.col_name, T1.col1, NULL AS col2
FROM  T1
LEFT JOIN  T2
  ON T1.col_name=  T2.col_name
WHERE T2.col_name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 'T2' AS tab_name, T2.col_name, NULL, T2.col2
FROM  T2
LEFT JOIN  T1
  ON T1.col_name=  T2.col_name
WHERE T1.col_name IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/419577)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ tab_name ║ col_name ║ col1 ║        col2         ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬══════╬═════════════════════╣
║ T1       ║ C        ║    3 ║                     ║
║ T1       ║ D        ║    4 ║                     ║
║ T2       ║ E        ║      ║ 2016-01-03 00:00:00 ║
║ T2       ║ F        ║      ║ 2016-01-02 00:00:00 ║
║ T2       ║ G        ║      ║ 2016-01-01 00:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: But what if I have two different tables with different columns, but both of them have one same column? I'm trying to apply your idea to my existing query but then I get error like The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @Josef Please ask new question with sample data http://sqlfiddle.com and desired output.

Comment: The idea and the question is the same,only difference is that two tables have different number of columns, but as I said both have one common column as in my example given in first post.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions.

Using `UNION ALL` together with an outer select with `GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(x) = 1`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT a FROM t2) as t12 GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(a) = 1
```

Using `UNION` to combine two `SELECT`s filtered by subqueries:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM t2)) UNION (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM t1))
```

Not sure which one is most performant!

[See it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff1f3/6).

Answer (score 0):

Try to intersect the two tables. you can see the  differences.

```
SELECT T1.col_name
FROM (
SELECT T1.col_name FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.col_name FROM T2
) T1
GROUP BY col_name
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY col_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no duplicates in either table, one approach uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, . . .
from (select t1.* from table1 t1
      union all
      select t2.* from table2 t2
     ) tt
group by col1, col2, . . .
having count(*) = 1;
```

Actually, you can relax the condition on not having duplicates, but then you need to specify what to do with them.